# How can I constantly read the serial port in windows 10 universal (C#)

Tags: c#, serial-port, win-universal-app

I want to read a serial port constantly and get the output in a textbox in my windows 10 universal app (C#). I found this code from the MS serial sample from https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialSample/CS :

```
   private async void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            if (serialPort != null)
            {
                dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);

                while (true)
                {
                    await ReadAsync(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.GetType().Name == "TaskCanceledException")
            {
                CloseDevice();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataReaderObject != null)
            {
                dataReaderObject.DetachStream();
                dataReaderObject = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);

        UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            reciveTextBox.Text = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

but when I call the *Listen()* function with a button click, some times it reads the port sometimes it doesn't.

Please give a solution that will constantly read the serial port and give the output in the textbox.

The full code of MainPage.xaml.cs is here: http://pastebin.com/dmsTUBmT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an example on GitHub: [Arduino_UWP_App](https://github.com/programmersommer/Arduino_UWP_App)

If to describe shortly. 
Here are main variables:

```
 private SerialDevice serialPort = null;
 DataReader dataReaderObject = null;
```

Don't forget to reference:

```
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
```

First you should find device

```
 string qFilter = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM3");
 DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(qFilter);

        if (devices.Any())
        {
            string deviceId = devices.First().Id;
            await OpenPort(deviceId);
        }
```

In the way like this you could open port:

```
   private async Task OpenPort(string deviceId)
    {
        serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);
        if (serialPort != null)
        {
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
        }
    }
```

And now you can listen for messages:

```
   while (true)
        {
            await Listen();
        }
```

.......

```
  private async Task Listen()
    {
            if (serialPort != null)
            {
                dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
                await ReadAsync(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }         
    }
```

.......

```
private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 256;  // only when this buffer would be full next code would be executed
        dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);   // Create a task object

        UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;    // Launch the task and wait until buffer would be full

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string strFromPort = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Maybe do you have the same BUT for usb device?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by manipulating the read timeout one can receive different responses. The lower the number (milliseconds) the higher the speed of reading and the bytes read are closer or equal to what used to be BytesAvailable.

The higher the number the slower the response and with fuller read buffer (which might include more than one response from the source device).

The original SerialSample code would show this and if it is modified to perform predetermined timed writes in a loop then one could see the expected responses being read in a different way for each timeout value.
Those who experiment with PLC devices would probably be able to see this easily knowing what kind of response to expect from particular PLC.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand how this can be related with the question "some times it reads the port sometimes it doesn't."